# Cycles and permutation

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Here's the problem:

a)Write each element of $[n-1]$ of a separate card, then randomly select any number of cards, and take the product of the numbers of written on them. Then we do this for all $2^{n-1}$ possible subsets of set $n-1$ cards. Finally we take the sum of the $2^{n-1}$ products we obtained. What is the sum?
b)Instead of considering all $2^{n-1}$ subsets, consider all k-element subsets of the $n-1$ cards. What is the sum of all $n-1 \choose k$ products obtained in that scenario?

Now I answered the first part using a recursive formula and got $F(n-1)=n!$ and so the required sum is $n!$ which is correct(hurray), but I don't know how to work out part b. Should I apply the same kind of recursive formula? Or try the signless stirling number? How do you go about showing the second part using a combinatorics argument? Any tips or advice is appreciated

Comment: Alternative solution for part a): expand $(1+1)(1+2)(1+3)\dotsb (1+(n-2))(1+(n-1))$.